# World of Warcraft Mount Purchase

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If I purchase a flying mount from the Blizzard store will it work for my character who is only level 41, or do I have to level and get the more advanced riding skills to use it?

Answer (score 9):

All three of the Blizzard Store mounts (the Heart of the Aspects, Winged Guardian, and Celestial Steed) work from Level 20 and 75 (slow ground) Riding Skill. They will not, however, allow the user to fly until the proper riding skills (225+ Riding, Flight Master's License/Cold Weather Flying) have been purchased (based on zone).

(Source: [Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Heart_of_the_Aspects), [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/item=54811))

Comment: You can't however use them to fly at level 20, you still need the higher skill level trained at level 60 to actually fly.

Comment: Probably better worded as: It will adapt to the current level of riding skill that you have.

Comment: @MatthewScharley and James Jiao: Appended based on comments. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the bought mounts can work from level 20, but will not fly until you buy the flight skill at level 60.